# SFP+ iSCSI Optic Transceiver: Dell VS Other

Tags: dell, iscsi, sfp

Out of curiosity, does anyone have any experience with Dell iSCSI SAN connected with SPF+ transceivers?

My question is about what makes this:
https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/10gb-iscsi-sfp-optical-adapter-customer-kit/apd/540-bbkj/networking#ratings_section

Different from any other SFP+ 10Gb SR dual LC Transceiver?

Is this a price goudge/markup scheme or is there any real difference them?

Thank you

Comment: The Dell sticker adds $300 to the price.

Comment: That what i was thinking but they really don't like us not using other SFP.
I wonder if the SAN validated the SFP manufacturer ID and refuses to connect.

Comment: @MaxSantos That is quite possible. Some devices don't really care about SFP branding, but others won't ever accept anything but "original". However, there are countless vendors for 100% compatible (=fake branded) modules with a reasonable price.

Comment: In the specs, Dell doesn't even mention that the module is likely 10GBASE-SR - which are 20-60€ without the brand markup.

Comment: Its true, they don´t say it is a 10Gb SR, but i think it is because other SANs can use them. Next time i go to the Datacenter i will try one out just to see if the SAN compaints.